# How to use multiple instances of Jquery-tabs.js in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm very new to HTML and jquery, and have been trying in vain to get multiple instances of the [jquery-tabs.js](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) widget to run twice within the same page on my website. Below is the HTML code for my first tab.

```
<div id="tabs-container">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul class="mctabs"> 
                <li><a href="#view1">ContentA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#view2">ContentB</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div><!--end tabs-->

        <div class="panel-container"> 
                <div id="view1"> 
                 <ul>
                    <li class="view1span1">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla </section>
                    </li>
                        <li class="view1span2">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla </section>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
                </div><!--end view1-->

            <div id="view2"> 
                 <ul>
                    <li class="view2span1">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla </section>
                    </li>
                        <li class="view2span2">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla </section>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
                </div><!--end view2-->
           </div><!--end panel-container-->
    </div><!--end tabs-container-->
```

And here is the code with the second tab

```
    <div id="container-next" class="slide" data-slide="3">

        <div id = "tabs2">
            <ul class = "mctabs">
                <li><a href = "#view5"> ContentC </a></li>
                <li><a href = "#view6"> ContentD </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end tabs2-->
   </div>

    <div class="container-12" data-tabber>

    <div id = "view5"> 

    <ul>
     <li class="grid-4">
        <section> blablablabla </section>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--end view5-->

    <div id = "view6"> 
    <ul>

        <li class="grid-4">
            <section> blablablabla </section>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!--end view6-->
      </div> <!--end container-12-->
    </div> <!-- end container-next-->
```

Two things happen when I try to get the tabs to work

1) The first tab's items completely disappear when I click on the header items for the 2nd tab.

2) The items in view 6 on the second tab do not show when I click on the corresponding tab for ContentD. And the below is shown in the HTML when I inspect the site.

```
<div id = "view6" style = "display: none;">...</div>
```

This isn't the full code for the site, so do let me know if you guys need anymore information.

Thanks for reading this lengthy question.

Comment: try to create fiddle that will show your issues.

Comment: Hi @kiran, so you recommend I put the code up on fiddle to share with everyone so that you guys can look at it better?

Comment: @ Kenneth Yong : yes, that will be helpful to everyone to see your problem and help you to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input :)

I went back to ask some colleagues about the issue, and it turns out that the issue I was facing was due to the previous web developer not placing the script for the assigning tabs and tabs2 in the proper place.

I'm currently trying to spend some time figuring out where the scripts are hidden, but thanks a bunch for everyone who spent time on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `<div id="tabs">` , which should include `<div class="panel-container">`, and not only `<ul class="mctabs">` .

Try this:

**First tab:**

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="mctabs"> 
            <li><a href="#view1">ContentA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#view2">ContentB</a></li>
        </ul> 


        <div class="panel-container"> 
            <div id="view1"> 
                <ul>
                    <li class="view1span1">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla1 </section>
                    </li>
                    <li class="view1span2">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla2 </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="view2"> 
                <ul>
                    <li class="view2span1">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla3 </section>
                    </li>
                    <li class="view2span2">
                        <section>Bla bla bla bla4 </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second tab:**

```
<div id="container-next" class="slide" data-slide="3">

    <div id = "tabs2">
        <ul class = "mctabs">
            <li><a href = "#view5"> ContentC </a></li>
            <li><a href = "#view6"> ContentD </a></li>
        </ul>



        <div class="container-12" data-tabber>

            <div id = "view5"> 

                <ul>
                    <li class="grid-4">
                        <section> blablablabla7 </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id = "view6"> 
                <ul>

                    <li class="grid-4">
                        <section> blablablabla8 </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

And the **script**:

```
<script>
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  $( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
</script>
```